# Reading .mdb or .accdb file from s3 bucket in AWS lambda function and converting it into excel or csv using python

Tags: python, ms-access, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a use case where I need to read tables from MS access file (.mdb or .accdb) which is placed on AWS s3 bucket and converting it into csv or excel file in AWS lambda function and again upload the converted file to s3 bucket.

I got the ways through pyodbc library but it's not working on AWS cloud especially when the file is placed on s3 bucket.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the S3 bucket isn't an SMB file share.

Download the database file to a SMB file server - a server running *Windows Server* or *Linux* with *Samba* - and access the file at that location.

Comment: Actually, I am ale to download the file from s3 bucket but couldn't able to convert it to excel.

Comment: You'll need a driver - _JET_ for mdb files, _ACE_ for accdb files - and a matching python library to read the data; Bing/Google for these. Then it should be a snap to write the data to an Excel file.